# Generating div on the fly with jQuery fails to load picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Jquery to diplay dialog on my page. Currently the div is written in my HTML, and I show or hide it when I need it with jQuery (open/close of .dialog() method). The "issue" is that the div is loaded at the start of the page and even if its not visible, the markup is still visible in the source. So I would like to generate the dive on the fly when I click on the button only.

here is my div :

```
    <div class="dialog" id="UploadDialog" title="Uploading...">
    <div>
    Your file <i><span id="fileinfo"></span></i> is being uploaded<br />
    <b>Estimate time </b><span id="temps"></span><br /><br />
    <b>Please wait</b><br /><br />
    <i>This window willclose automatically at the end of the upload</i>
    </div>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="33%"></td>
            <td width="33%" align="left">
                <img alt="loading..." id="imgloading" src="Image/loader.gif" /><br /><br />
                <input type="button" value="Cancel Upload" onclick="javascript:cancel();"/>
            </td>
            <td width="33%"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
    </div>
```

Currently at the begning of the javascript :

```
$("#UploadDialog").dialog({
    width: 400
});
$("#UploadDialog").dialog("close");
```

And when I click I fill the span and then         `$("#UploadDialog").dialog("open");`

Im already using a div wrapper for other dialog on my page which is as follow :

```
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
```

and then I would like in the js file to call on click :

```
$("#wrapper").empty();
$("#wrapper").append("<div class='dialog' id='UploadDialog' .....");//all the div content
$("#UploadDialog").dialog({
    width: 400
});
```

However this wont load properly since the dimension of the dialog is not the same as when I use the first method (Html + open/close) and the GIF wont load (picutre not found icon even though there are no 404 ressource not found in the console)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `dialog` again after appending it to div

```
$("#wrapper").empty();
$("#wrapper").append("<div class='dialog' id='UploadDialog' .....");/
$("#UploadDialog").dialog({
width: 400
});
```

Comment: Yes, I should have mentionned that I already do that, that doesn't change anything to the issue. The image is not loaded.